# Express res.download not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, download

I've been stuck on this for some time now and I'm running out of options. I need to download a file from a Node.js Express server to a Vue.js client. I have a button that when clicked, triggers the end point on the server and is seemingly able to run `res.download` without any issues. Here is my code:

### SimulationController.js

```
var thisPath = path.resolve(".") + '/public/' + 'test.txt';
console.log(thisPath)

res.download(thisPath, function (err) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        console.log('download complete')
    }
});
```

The file path output by the `console.log` is correct and I'm pretty sure `res.download` is able to find the file becuase if I input an invalid path, the error is logged telling me so. Instead I just get 'download complete' but nothing happens in the browser, no error messages in an console, nothing.

I have tried setting the headers manually like so:

```
// res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.txt');
// res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

I have tried using relative and absolute file paths and I have tried using `path.resolve`. Every time, I believe it is finding the file as I get 'download complete' output but still nothing in the browser.

Do I need to do something on the client? Here is my code just in case:

### ViewSimulation.vue

```
download : function () {
    SimulationService.downloadSimulation(this.SimulationParameters.simulationFilePath)
    console.log('downloaded')
}
```

Note: This all runs with no errors - "downloaded" is output in the browsers console.

### SimulationService.js

```
downloadSimulation (simulationFilePath) {
    return Api().post('/download', { simulationFilePath })
},
```

### Api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081/'
    })
}
```

Eventaully, I need to be able to download files from a location outside of the server directory. At the moment I am struggling to get a text file to download from the public directory.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

edit:

### Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt"
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2018 18:56:40 GMT
ETag: W/"d-162e9839664"
Last-Modified: Sat, 21 Apr 2018 18:42:17 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Have discovered that 'content-length' changes depending on whats in the text document. 13 is for 'Hello World' with a new line.

Comment: You probably want to use `var thisPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public/' , 'test.txt');`

Comment: @BrahmaDev Just tried that, unfortunately, the same result. Thank you for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Try adding the filename as `res.download(thisPath, 'test.txt'`...` And then add (to the question here) the response headers you get. You can find response headers in the `Network` tab of browser console.

Comment: @BrahmaDev, I have added the response headers as per you're request - hopefully, something useful in there!

Comment: That looks OK. I think I get your problem now. You want the file to download using the browsers' download manager.

Comment: If that is the case, you need to see this : https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743